# WordPress Child Theme styling not always working

Tags: css, wordpress

I manually installed my WP child theme. The stylesheet works good for most things but I keep running against the odd thing or 2 where it reverts back to the parent theme stylesheet. Right now specifically I can't adjust my footer bottom margin.

Here's the Enqueque I have in my functions.php in the child theme:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/style.css' );
 }
```

Any idea why my child theme is acting this way? Thanks

Comment: Is your child theme's style.css enqueued as well? And does the parent theme use any stylesheets other than style.css?

Comment: 1) Not sure if the style.css is enquequed also. I thought the functions.php took care of that??

Comment: 2) Parent theme does have other base styles but those aren't the ones that the footer code is pulling from. It's the standard stylesheet from the parent theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you might need to enqueue the child theme's style.css as well. Doing it this way sets the parent style as a dependency for the child style and makes sure they get loaded in the correct order. [Read more here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array( 'parent-style' ), wp_get_theme()->get('Version') );
}
```

Comment: Also don't forget to clear your cache when updates are not taking effect in case your stylesheet was cached

Comment: Having a similar issue on another website. I'm not fighting against the standard parent stylesheet this time, I'm fighting against another CSS sheet which is part of it. You get to choose a theme color and based on that it imports another stylesheet. This one is called main.green.css. So, I think it must be a similar issue. I put the code you suggested above into the functions.php but it's still not working right.

Comment: If your parent theme uses more than one .css file, you should enqueue them all and make sure the dependencies are set so that they will load in the correct order. You want all the parent stuff to load first and the child stuff last so that you will properly override what you want to. I can't write all the correct code for you without knowing what parent theme you're using because it will be different depending on the theme. But just do some more research on the link I've posted and in the documentation for `wp_enqueue_style` and you should be alright. @MegBogart